# Get Disk IO performance counter

Tags: powershell

I need to get Page Faults and Disk IO of system while a particular process is running.

I can get Page Faults but not able to get Disk IO:

```
 $arrayDIO = @()
 $arrayPf = @()
 $cmdProcess = start-process cmd -passthru
   while (-not $cmdProcess.HasExited) {
        $arrayDIO += %{ (Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process).IOWriteOperationsPerSec }
        $arrayPf += %{ (Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_memory).PageFaultsPerSec }
    sleep 2
  }
 $arrayPf | Measure-Object -Average -Maximum -Minimum | Out-File  -Filepath C:\Details.txt
 $arrayDIO | Measure-Object -Average -Maximum -Minimum | Out-File  -Filepath C:\Details.txt -append
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than **Get-WMIObject**, use the built-in command for getting performance data, **Get-Counter**:

`Get-Counter '\Process(*)\IO Data Operations/sec'`

`Get-Counter '\Memory\Page Faults/sec'`